# allow-foreign in schXSLT

Tags: validation, xslt, schematron

I'm evaluating schXSLT for Schematron validation. Currently we use Skeleton, which has the ability to use other language elements (e.g. XSLT) using `allow-foreign`.
Does schXSLT support `allow-foreign` as well?

Comment: I think the current version by default for XSLT 2 and 3 pulls in `xsl:include`, `xsl:import`, `xsl:key`, `xsl:function` and (for XSLT 3) package related XSLT declarations.

Comment: See https://github.com/schxslt/schxslt/tree/v1.9.2 listing "xsl:accumulator (XSLT 3.0)
xsl:import (XSLT 1.0, XSLT 2.0, XSLT 3.0), xsl:import-schema (XSLT 2.0, XSLT 3.0),xsl:include (XSLT 1.0, XSLT 2.0, XSLT 3.0), xsl:use-package (XSLT 3.0)" in addition to `xsl:key` and `xsl:function`.